# Where to run Elastic Map Reduce CLI from or use an alternative to EMR CLI?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, emr

Where do I let EMR CLI run as a recommended case? From my local Linux workstation or from a AWS Virtual Server?

Ar there (better) alternatives to EMR CLI, in case I want to programmatively access my clusters and perform Map Reduce jobs?

Comment: What do you mean "Is it possible that I need to run elastic-mapreduce directly from S3"? Can you provide details how do you launch cluster?

Comment: I am running the cluste(s)r from the AWS/S3 Web interfaces, the ruby client itself is running on my Ubuntu 14.04.  I followed the official docs and the readme file. I will try tonight without proxy, I hope it was the root cause. If not I still will need some guidance. I need to get this going quickly.

Comment: Now you question seems non-useful. Can explain what do you try to do and what kind of problems did you meet? BTW: EMR Ruby CLI provide arguments to use proxy.

Comment: Hi, I did set the Proxy in the config files.I did alter the question now altogether to be more simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hadoop Streaming](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming)
[mrjob](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/)
[dumbo](https://klbostee.github.io/dumbo/)
[hadoopy](http://www.hadoopy.com/en/latest/)
[pydoop](http://pydoop.sourceforge.net/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is no reason to run EMR Ruby CLI on AWS cluster instead of your local machine.

Currently (as I know) there is no CLI alternative for EMR Ruby CLI.
The [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) doesn't support full stack of EMR API.

If you want to automate EMR usage (some repeatedly use cases for example) you can try to use [AWS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/code) for Java, Python and other languages.

Comment: Do you mean Python Boto? https://github.com/boto/boto

Comment: Yes, boto for example, but you shouldn't use it if your use case simple unrepeatable job.

Comment: Use case is Terrabytes of data in my case.